# How to change the owner for all Stored Procedures at once in Sybase IQ

Tags: sybase, sap-iq

Sybase IQ is new to me.
In my Schema, I have 225 tables and 100 stored procedures. Attempting to alter the owner of every object. I was able to change the owner of Tables using the ALTER command. However, it is not working for stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to change procedure's owner on IQ. But maybe you can use workaround --
How about "setuser" ? Using "setuser" to set your current dbuser as the procedure's owner... eg.

```
setuser 'oldprocowner';
call <procedure_name>;
...
```